# Swift after dismiss Current ViewController then the Presenting ViewController not calling viewWillAppear()

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am using two view controller `VC1` and `VC2`. Here, VC1 button click to `Present Modally` and `Over Full Screen` presentation with `Cross Dissolve` Transition to presenting VC2. Now, from VC2 dismiss then I didn’t get call VC1 `viewWillAppear()`.

I am not using code base for Present model. I am using `Storyboard Segue`.

Why it happening and how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear),

> Note
>
> If a view controller is presented by a view controller inside of a
>   popover, this method is not invoked on the presenting view controller
>   after the presented controller is dismissed.

So according to the documentation when a ViewController presents another ViewController modally this method will not be called. To fix this you need to use

```
func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, 
  completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

and move(or repeat) some of viewWillLoad logic to completion handler.

Comment: what is the alternative solution?

Comment: @Shreeram Bhat Same issue I am also facing. I cant understand your solution, Can you please provide detail codebase?

Comment: @Shreeram Bhat I can't understand above answer. Explain bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Change presentation to `Full screen` or If you want to stick to `Over Full Screen` then make vc2 delegate of vc1 and call delegate method on dismiss.

To understand the concept you can refer to : https://medium.com/livefront/why-isnt-viewwillappear-getting-called-d02417b00396